# Reading & Writing Bootstrap Slider (NOT a Carousel) data-slider-value from C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, twitter-bootstrap, uislider

I am new to .NET & Bootstrap and am required to use the .ASPX single file ASP.NET type code AND use Bootstrap and its slider.   I have the Slider control below

```
<input type="text"
       runat="server"
       value="7"
       class="slider-horizontal"
       id="_sl1"
       data-slider-min="0"
       data-slider-max="10"
       data-slider-step="1"
       data-slider-value="7"
       data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
       data-slider-selection="after"
       data-slider-tooltip="show">
```

and need to set the ***data-slider-value*** in the server side C# code in the on page_load event, then read it back on post_back, BUT I don't appear to be able to do this, and can find no information on how to do it except client side via javascript. I see the ***value*** property but setting that appears to do nothing.

I believe the problem is the text box used for the slider is mapped to 
`System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText` by .NET, hence the presence of the ***Value*** property, but the `Slider` properties I see in the HTML code are not recognised in the server C# code so can't be accessed.  Any help or pointers to appropriate information as to how to then use this control to access the values on the server side would be most welcome. I have spent some days trying to find  a solution, not helped by the lax terminology that means Slider picks up Carousel related links!  I've also followed Bootstrap courses , at least 3 so far and they too fail to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to everyone who tidied up the mess I made of this post, and now my answer to my problem, it is simple, which is probably why I spent days looking for it. Use the Attribute method of the control.

.Attributes.Add("data-slider-value", theValue);